# Rails object value won't display on view page. No errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an app that allows users to comment on a blog post called a "work". Here are the model relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works  
  has_many :comments

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :work
```

There's a form on the Works show page that allows users to post a comment:

```
<%= form_for([@work, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post feedback or contribute content
    to this work!" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Since the comment form is on the Works page, the Works controller has the following build logic for a comment:

```
def show 
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @work.comments.build
  @comment.user = current_user
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Work", trackable_id: @work).all
  @comments = @work.comments.order("created_at DESC").where(work_id: @work).all 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
```

The Comments controller then creates the comment:

```
def create
    @work = Work.find(params[:work_id])
    @comment = @work.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      #flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render 'home#index'
     end
  end
```

**My problem is that the Works show page will display the user's name that submitted the comment but for some reason it will not display the value of the "content" field, even though there is a content value in the database!** I don't get any error messages. I simply get an empty box where the content text should be.

Here is the Works show page that displays the content (minus the html formatting):

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<%= image_tag @comment.user.photo.url(:avatar) %> <%= link_to @comment.user.full_name, @comment.user if @comment.user %>
<%= @comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

If I replace @comment.content with something like @comment.work_id, I'll get the number "1" to display on the webpage. As I mentioned before, there is indeed a valid value for content stored in the database. Why won't it display? Why isn't there an error?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view code, you are iterating over `@comments` and storing each one as `comment` (note lack of `@`) - then in the loop you are referring to `@comment` which is probably something else entirely.

Change the `@comment` to be `comment`.

Comment: Good lord. That's all I needed to do?! Thanks again seven! I really need to stop working on this so late at night :D .